# max media queries do not apply

Tags: html, media-queries, media

I am trying to do tests with media queries but it does not apply the max-width, instead the min width does

I leave my css code

```
body{
    background: grey;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
    body {
        background-color:violet;}
}



@media (min-width: 1220px) {
    body{
        background-color: tomato;
    }
    
}
```

any idea why it happens?

Comment: You should try it vice-versa. Maximum cannot be 500px and minimum 1220px. Max < Min ? Makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works, if width less then 500, background-color:violet;
if width much then 1220, background-color: tomato; and between background: grey;